# Web deploy failing, says DESTINATION NOT REACHABLE

Tags: visual-studio, iis, msdeploy

I honestly don't know where to start apart from mentioning I've tried absolutely everything and I feel like banging my head against the wall!

I've configured my IIS according to the Microsoft docs and also added Web Deploy 3.6.

In my services I have the following running:
[image]

In my windows firewall I have opened port 8172:
[image]

In my IIS I have enabled remote connections:
[image]

Within IIS I have a Site which points to an empty folder, when I right click -> Deploy -> Configure Web Deploy publishing I get this:

[image]

Using this, I've set up a publish profile in VS like so:

[image]

But get this error why I try and 'Validate' the connection:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("server2021"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)
This error indicates that you cannot connect to the server. Make sure the service URL is correct, firewall and network settings on this computer and on the server computer are configured properly, and the appropriate services have been started on the server.
Error details:
Could not connect to the remote computer ("server2021"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.
Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I can't even remote to this server, I'm accessing it using TeamViewer.

I've viewed EventViewer logs on my local machine and it just says the same error which VS is spitting out.

I honestly don't know what I'm doing and I'd really really appreciate any help

Comment: Are you sure when use `SERVER2021` in url,  it can be mapped to your server IP correctly? Test https://SERVER2021 in browser to check. Another thing is that https use 443xxx as port.

Comment: @BruceZhang When I go to SERVER2021 it redirects me to http://server2021/no_account and then says "server2021 redirected you too many times."

Comment: You need to solve this issue first. It usually caused by url rewrite. Check it if the incorrect rule caused too much redirect.